# Traveling after my German residence permit expires

Tags: schengen, germany, canadian-citizens

I have a question regarding the Schengen border rules. I, a Canadian citizen, entered Germany on February 1st, 2017. I got my student visa on March 3, and it will expire on June 20. However, I will be traveling in Europe (I will enter Italy on June 19 and stay there until I return home on June 29th) after the expiry of my residence permit. As I understand, the border code states that the time I lived under my residence permit does NOT count towards my 90 day limit:

> 1. For intended stays on the territory of the Member States of a duration of no more than 90 days in any 180-day period, which entails considering the 180-day period preceding each day of stay, the entry conditions for third-country nationals shall be the following:
>      ...
> 2. For the purposes of implementing paragraph 1, the date of entry shall be considered as the first day of stay on the territory of the Member States and the date of exit shall be considered as the last day of stay on the territory of the Member States. Periods of stay authorised under a residence permit or a long-stay visa shall not be taken into account in the calculation of the duration of stay on the territory of the Member States.

Source: http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=CELEX:32006R0562

However, I don't want this to cause problems during my travels. I contacted the German visa office and they told me flat out NO (to traveling after my permit expires), saying that I have to stay out of Schengen for another 90 days. But then the rule in the border code doesn't say that. So, I need some guidance. Who do I contact from here?

Some additional details:
- I will be entering Italy on the 19th of June (one day before my residence permit expires), and remaining there until I fly back

Comment: Is your student visa a Schengen visa as, if it is, the rules apply? If you're unsure, upload an image of it with your personal info redacted.

Comment: When you asked, did you tell them you are from a generally visa-free country?

Comment: @Dorothy No idea, it is an Aufenthaltstitel

Comment: @chirlu Not explicitly, but they looked through my Canadian passport.

Comment: You can also always call the Bundespolizei up and ask them. They are the ones doing the immigration checks. They have offices on every mayor travel hub. Probably Frankfurt Airport is the best. Find their phone number, ask to speak to someone in German and explain, or go to the nearest airport, find their office and simply ask them. They also have twitter accounts. If you call them, do not call them at 110!

Comment: @simbabque Indeed. I e-mailed the Frankfurt border police this morning. He confirmed that I must leave the Schengen area for 1 day and re-enter as a tourist. He also confirmed that my stay under a residence permit is not included in the calculation. So, I am just looking at the technicalities of this now. Where do I go, where do I get my passport stamped etc. It would be cool if any of you know details.

Comment: London I guess. You don't need a visa, it's a short flight and always worth a visit. Monaco is not Schengen, but they just let you in if you have a Schengen visa, there's no border control, so that won't work.

Comment: @simbabque I will be traveling in Italy, so I'm thinking Croatia is pretty close.